# Is it possible to store instances of custom class in Vuex/(Vue data)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-reactivity

According to vue documentation, it is not possible to store anything besides plain objects. (https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data). I always use vuex as a DI container, I see it from this point of view. It keeps vue away from my application business logic, and makes possible describe business rules only using JS with no dependencies. But that approach breaks vue dev tool, and for some reason not all tests pass. 
Is there a way to circumvent this restriction? For example class instances can be created in getters rather than in mutations. But it does not work for me because some constructors of my classes have side effects (It's not a best practice, but that what i have).

Comment: Your description is so abstract that I cannot understand all. Could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely store class instances in the store state.

I generally store arrays of models, which is really useful to keep logic in one place.

Something like:

```
Api.load('/api/users').then(res => commit('users', res.data.map(User.create)))
```