# Methods missing from Javascript Class inside Vuex state

Tags: javascript, oop, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm using Nuxt framework alongside Vuex to store data in my web site but I'm facing trouble when I want to use a class directly in the state.

With a model `cart.js` defined like this:

```
export class Cart {

    constructor(ownedID) {
        this._created = new Date();
        this._lastUpdated = new Date();
        this._ownerID = ownedID || 'visitor'
        this._items = []
    }

     getItem (articleNumber) {
          console.log(this._items)
    }

    ...
}
```

And my store's module `cart.js`

```
import { Cart } from "~/models/cart";

const state = () => ({
    cart: new Cart()
})

const mutations = {
    ADD_ITEM(state, newItem) {
        console.log(state.cart)
    }
}

...
```

When the `ADD_ITEM(state, newItem)` mutation is called the `getItem(articleNumber)` function is missing and thus I receive the `TypeError: state.cart.getItem is not a function` error.

This is the result of the `console.log`:

```
__ob__: Object { value: {…}, dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }
​
   _created: 
   _item:
   _lastUpdated:
   _ownerID:
```

This is a sandbox link of my setup.

[Nuxt vuex sandbox error](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-tree-sbrnq?file=/store/index.js)

Does anyone have a clue about my issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I have changed the post with the sandbox link as requested. The issue is still there. I simply used dispatch to trigger an action which triggers my mutation.

Comment: according to this post you cannot put class instances in vuex store
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006376/is-it-possible-to-store-instances-of-custom-class-in-vuex-vue-data

Comment: Your code works fine in Vue/Vuex, but not Nuxt. For some reason Nuxt strips the prototypal inheritance info out of state objects, which means it can't find the prototype method created by the class.  (In Vue/Vuex without Nuxt, there's no `TypeError` and `getItem` works.)

Comment: @ggirodda according to that link `You can absolutely store class instances in the store state.` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue accepts only plain objects & Observes only native object properties, It ignores the `prototype` properties. According to the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)

> **The object must be plain**: native objects such as browser API objects and prototype properties are ignored

In your case, your using a `class` which creates variables in plain object and  methods in prototype`(__proto__)`, That's why state is unable to find `getItem` method. You need to use `plain objects` instead of classes

[image].

Comment: It works ok in Vue/Vuex, just not Nuxt, so this explanation isn't quite right.

Comment: @Dan Yeah you're right, It worked for met too, But It mentioned in the [Vue Documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data#:~:text=native%20objects%20such%20as%20browser%20API%20objects%20and%20prototype%20properties%20are%20ignored). I think this is also wrong. isn't it?

Comment: The doc link discusses reactivity, not existence/accessibility.  It means only that prototype properties won't be reactive, which is *mostly* true.  What they don't mention is that the prototype properties are at least accessible and can be used in a template, just like the prototype method `getItem`.  In Nuxt they're not even accessible and don't exist, because Nuxt seems to unlink the prototype of its state objects, removing all prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Does anyone have any more information why it isn't working in Nuxt? Is this a bug or intentional?

Comment: @RolfB I think it's related to this discussion: https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm/issues/255